# SharePoint 2013 designer workflow with 2010 platform is not working

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am creating a 2013 designer workflow to update a list item. While saving checking for error no errors found, but after deployed list item is not updating. The column of workflow is not showing Inprogress/Complete.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check next workflow options for your list:
Creating a new item will start this workflow.
Changing an item will start this workflow.

2) Try to start workflow manually and check workflow history list.

Comment: from where can i check the historylist/ is it on item selection?

Comment: Go to the list -> Select Item-> Open Ribbon menu-> select "Workflow" -> There you can check workflow statistics. Select workflow instant -> check status/history